# What is the equivalent of a buck converter for AC voltage?

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, buck, step-down

A have researched and found that a buck converter is used for stepping down voltage in DC applications.

However, my application uses AC current. I have christmas lights that plug into the wall and I wanted to remove some bulbs. Now I am using a resistor, but I don't want the resistor because it is hot so I considered stepping down the voltage to achieve this without the device getting hot.

So how can I step down voltage on an AC application? Essentially, this would be the equivalent of a buck converter which is used for DC applications.

Comment: Use a transformer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transformer would probably be the most efficient. An electronic dimmer would probably be a close second.

A transformer would probably be less expensive, but finding one for the right voltage may be difficult. Transformers can be wired to "buck" the voltage. To do that, you connect the primary in series with the secondary. That creates an autotransformer, so there is no isolation.

With a dimmer, all you need to do id dial back the voltage.

With either, you need to figure out what to do about an enclosure. You can buy dimmers designed to mount in a wall box. Getting a suitable enclosed transformer may be more difficult. It is unlikely that any solution will conform to electrical codes.

Comment: It was a hard choice. But I chose yours because you offered two solutions.

Comment: I don't know where to begin with transformers. How do I calculate? Where do I find? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

In AC, voltage can be easily reduced or boosted by using a transformer instead of going for expensive power electronic circuitry.